# Differential Encoder Modulo8 Adder in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to make a 3-bit differential encoder in matlab. My code works, but as I increase the data size, it gets very slow, so I want to write it without a for loop, but I couldn't find how to do it.  Could you help?

my code is as below. First ı wrote a function for a modulo 8 adder. Then I used it in for loop like this

```
function c=modulo8(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3)
x1=mod(a1+a2,2);
r0=a1*b1;
x2=mod(a2+b2+r0,2);
r1=mod((a2*b2)+(a2*r0)+(b2*r0),2);
x3=mod(a3+b3+r1,2); 
c=[x3 x2 x1];
```

Here is my main code;

```
diff1=0;

diff2=0;

diff3=0;

diffenc=[];

datas=randi(2,1,10e3)-1;

data=reshape(datas,8,length(datas)/8);

data=transpose(data);

for ii=1:1:length(data)

diffen=modulo8(diff1,diff2,diff3,data(ii,8),data(ii,4),data(ii,1));

diff1=diffen(1,3);

diff2=diffen(1.2);

diff3=diffen(1,1);

difenc=[diffenc;diffen];

end
```

Comment: I'll try to look at this more in depth later, but the first glaring problem I see is that you are growing the result array `difenc` on each loop. MATLAB should have warned you about that because it takes time to reallocate array each time you go beyond its allocated size. You know the final size of this array (length(data)x3) ahead of time, so it should be preallocated before the loop. (Note that using `length` is also slightly problematic, but that's a separate discussion.)